# Add IF ELSE statements to PHP code, to specify colour change in text

Tags: php

I currently have a WordPress plugin installed, which sends an email to the owner listing "Key Dates" and their details.

Currently, if the due date has already passed, it will change the text to Red on the email, stating Originally Due on X date (as below screenshot)

Current Email Template:

[image: image 1]

I would like to make a small modification to this, where the text is coloured as below:

Due within 30 days – Green

Due within 15 days – Yellow

Due less than 15 days/Overdue – Red

I think I need to add some IF/ELSE statements to the below code in the “propertyhive-email-schedule.php” file, however I am not quite sure of the correct code:

```
$details = '';
$schedule_start_date = new DateTime($start_date);
  if ( $due_date < $schedule_start_date ){
        // was due in the past
        $details = '<span style="color:#900">' .
         __( 'Originally due on', 'propertyhive' ) 
        . ' ' . $due_date->format('jS M') . '</span>';
```

Could I please get some assistance/pointers on the correct code to put in over here please to make the changes stated above?
The PHP file itself is not too big, happy to attach the entire file if it makes it easier?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you are right. Add `if elseif` to your code

Comment: How do I specify IF <15days?

Comment: `if ((due_date - start_date) < 15) ` something like this

Comment: Ok thanks, will try that. 
If I needed to specify IF between 30-16days due, how would I achieve this?

Comment: @shaikh441 Please take basic PHP courses on how to compare variables and how to use _if_ control statement

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php

$earlier = new DateTime("2022-07-18");
$later = new DateTime("2022-07-21");

$diff = $later->diff($earlier)->format("%a"); //3 days

if ($diff <= 15) {
    echo "<p style='color:red;'>" . $diff . " days</p>";
} else if ($diff > 15 && $diff <= 30) {
    echo "<p style='color:yellow;'>" . $diff . " days</p>";
} else {
    //$diff > 30
    echo "<p style='color:green;'>" . $diff . " days</p>";
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Result :

[image]

An **if/else statement (conditions)** uses operators such as greater than (>), equals (=) or smaller than (<) to compare values.

Once you have calculated the number of days between two dates, you can compare to your limits (0 to 15, 16 to 30, over 30) and apply the color your want as a style to the p element.